# @ character became %40 after setting in a $.param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS in my project. One of the function in my controller is to check if the inputted email already exist in the database.If it exists, the system will notify the user that it is already been used. To do that, I have to use `$http` with `$params`. However, even if the inputted email already exist, no feedback is given by the system. So I checked what's the value being checked by alerting the `$params`.

```
$scope.pop=function(email){
   $params=$.param({
       'email':email
   })
   alert($params)
}
```

I found out that the `@` character in the email became `%40`. For example: I input **d_unknown@yahoo.com**, it became **d_unknown%40yahoo.com**. 
I tried to check the original data by:

```
$scope.pop=function(email){
   alert(email)
}
```

And it looks fine, nothing changes. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: That is URI encoding, whatever you add into URL most of the special characters get encoded, does it making problem to you?

Comment: So your server does not understand URL encoding? That seems unlikely. Where in the chain exactly does the value get lost? `$param` works as expected.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of `$.param()`. You haven't given us enough information to help you. Why do you need `$.param()`? Are you using a server that doesn't understand URI encoding?

Answer (score 1):

It's the server's job to turn the URL encoded email address back into its original value. So your JavaScript is working perfectly, there's nothing to do there. Your server code is what needs to be fixed.

And if the application on the server isn't even decoding parameters before it's running the query against the database, it makes me feel like you may have some security issues to fix as well. Make sure that your parameters are decoded and cleaned before they are used in SQL queries. You can read more on cleaning parameters and SQL injection [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not really a problem, as you can see from [RFC 2936](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), section 2.4:

> For original character sequences that contain non-ASCII characters,
>      however, the situation is more difficult. Internet protocols that
>      transmit octet sequences intended to represent character sequences
>      are expected to provide some way of identifying the charset used, if
>      there might be more than one [RFC2277].  However, there is currently
>      no provision within the generic URI syntax to accomplish this
>      identification. An individual URI scheme may require a single
>      charset, define a default charset, or provide a way to indicate the
>      charset used.

However, if you really want to do this, you could use the method [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to *decode* this *URL* this way:

```js
var email = "d_unknown%40yahoo.com";
console.log(decodeURIComponent(email));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is beacause all special characters get encoded.
But you can decode the string before you use it with `decodeURIComponent()` (in js, but there are functions for php and all the others to)

Comment: oh sorry, you must use `decodeURIComponent`. I changed it in my answer